# Does general relativity predict that the gravitational field of a black hole would be uniform about its center of mass?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes

Black holes are typically represented by extreme distortions of space, where space is so bent, that it reaches a single point (i.e., the singularity).

Further, they are almost always depicted as having a flat disc of mass orbiting the singularity (i.e., the accretion disc). This suggests that its gravitational field is not uniform, but instead depends upon the angle of observation, and not just the distance to the center of its mass.

Comments below suggest the plane of the accretion disc is due to the angular momentum of the black hole, and not gravity.

If so, why? Specifically, what force mediates this, if it's not gravity?

See, e.g., [this image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole#/media/File:Black_Holes_-_Monsters_in_Space.jpg).

What does general relativity actually predict regarding the shape of a black hole, and its sidedness?

Comment: Have you read about [event horizons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_horizon#Event_horizon_of_a_black_hole) ?

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure that answers the question. I'm looking for an explanation of the predicted topology. I'm familiar with the basics, and looking for an answer as to whether the gravity is in fact one-sided, and if so, then why?

Comment: Spacetime "inside" and "outside" obey the same physical laws.  Gravity works the same way and the same metric applies.  I'm not sure what else you are asking, if anything ?  You might also try the [PBS Spacetime channel on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC7_gcs09iThXybpVgjHZ_7g) which has a lot of good videos explaining the technical stuff in (something close to) plain English.

Comment: A star generates a gravitational field that propagates in every direction, just like a point charge generates a field that propagates in every direction. I'm not asking about the gravity inside the black hole. I'm asking whether a black hole also generates a gravitational field that propagates in every direction, like an ordinary mass. And again, I'm familiar with the basics, perhaps a bit beyond the basics.

Comment: *imagine viewing a black hole from the side, so that its center is in the plane of observation*  A black hole is not a 2-D shape.  It is, for want of a better expression, a spheroid.

Comment: It's like dropping a very big ball on a rubber sheet - this will produce a curved 3D surface, that will have a bottom to it, the singularity. We can construct a plane that passes through this point, and is parallel to the planes that are perpendicular to the shape. Now imagine viewing the black hole from the plane that passes through the singularity. Is gravity equal on both sides of this plane? I'm asking for what general relativity actually predicts.

Comment: Black holes have huge angular momentum, with speeds at a significant fraction of *c*, which leads to [frame-dragging](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame-dragging). Also see https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/20292/16685

Answer (score 3):

General relativity says that black holes have only three characteristics: mass, angular momentum, and charge. Astrophysical black holes are expected to have zero charge, but most of them have very large angular momenta. This angular momentum is the angular momentum that came in with the accreting matter. Only in the special case of zero angular momentum would a black hole be spherically symmetric.

Comment: Thank you, this is very concise. Why does the angular momentum determine the plane of the accretion disk? And what force mediates this?

Answer (score 2):

If I have understood correctly, you seem to have the conceptual image of a black hole as two-dimensional plane, like a circle, sitting in three dimensional space; hence having some orientation. As others have commented, a black hole's (horizon's) *shape* is just the surface of a sphere. In GR the simplest example of a black hole is the Schwarzschild black hole, the spacetime of which is described by the [Schwarzschild metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_metric). This is the generic spacetime for the exterior of a spherically symmetric mass (i.e. the same as a non-rotating star or planet). You can therefore think of the gravitational effects of a black hole, outside of its horizon, as equivalent to any other massive body. Hopefully this clarifies that its shape really is just a three-dimensional sphere.

I would also just urge you to google 'black hole' and read the wikipedia page and other online resources as this more than answers your questions.

EDIT -- To make this more concrete, Birkhoff's theorem states that the exterior of *any* spherical, non-rotating massive body is described generally by the Schwarzschild metric, or the Reissner–Nordström metric in the case of charged bodies. The 'spherically symmetric' part implies the gravitational force felt by an observer only depends on radius, not on any angular components (as evident from the metrics).

EDIT2 - As your original question has changed substantially and continues to change topics, and to try and answer your questions in the comments, I'll sum up the answer to your original question and your current question.

Original:

> Does general relativity predict that a black hole would be flat

A: No, its horizon is three dimensional, a sphere.

Current:

> Does general relativity predict that the gravitational field of a black hole would uniform about its center of mass?

A: If the black hole is spherically symmetric, then the gravitational field is also spherically symmetric, depending only on radius $r$. If the black hole is not spherically symmetric then the gravitational field strength also depends on angular coordinates, described by the [Kerr solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr_metric).

This is not in agreements with your claim that 'gravity isn't uniform'; gravity isn't somehow inherently non-symmetric. It simply means the curvature of spacetime depends on matter and energy.

Comment: Thanks, so then typical representations of black holes where there is a plane upon which matter rotates, are inaccurate? Such as the one I linked to above?

Comment: In the image you linked, the black hole horizon is spherical - although in reality all physical black holes have some angular momentum and are not spherically symmetric: this solution is known as the [Kerr black hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_black_hole), and it's *shape* is deformed slightly, but that is not related to your question. It's the accession disk that appears to be localised in a 2 dimensional plane - see [this question](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/8275/accretion-disks-why-are-they-disk-shaped-rather-than-spherical) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: If gravity were truly uniform, then why would there be a single plane for the accretion disk? Either gravity is not uniform, or there is some other force, or set of forces, that determines the plane of the accretion disk.

Comment: You seem to be getting confused, as in your other comment where you say "So it seems to be accepted that gravity is in fact not uniform around a black hole". The 'uniformity' of gravity only depends on whether the *object/mass/black-hole* is spherically symmetric. There is a single plane because of the initial angular momentum of the black-hole - nothing to do with gravity. The gravity around a black-hole acts exactly the same as the gravity around any massive body. There is *no* angular preference unless the system initially has some angular momentum, and is hence non-spherically symmetric.

Comment: The comment below states that black holes are not symmetric, and therefore, they do not produce uniform gravitational fields, which means that both position (i.e., angle) and distance will be relevant.

Comment: So you're saying that the angular momentum of the black hole determines the plane of the accretion disk. Why? What force mediates this?

Comment: Your original question has changed substantially, where you originally asked about the dimensionality and topology of a black hole. Now I'm not sure what you're asking, as it's more of a statement than anything. Non spherically symmetric spacetimes (i.e. with angular momentum) depend on angular coordinates. Spherically symmetric spacetimes do not. This is true of any massive objects, not just black holes.

Answer (score 0):

> Stated differently, imagine viewing a black hole from the side,

[Link to original version of question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/revisions/496289/1)

I suspect that you're taking too literally the popular depictions of black holes as a kind of inescapable 'drain' in space, e.g.,

[image]

[Image credit](https://www.crunchyroll.com/forumtopic-789061/black-holes-are-confusing?pg=1)

These type of 'rubber sheet' diagrams to help visualize the spatial curvature are often misunderstood. The direction out of the plane of these diagrams does *not* correspond to an actual spatial direction.

A spherical (non-rotating) black hole is spherically symmetric, i.e., it 'looks' the same from any direction (though the view of background will change - see, for example, [this simulated view looking towards a spherical black hole from an orbit about it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_9nBPNB-JI)).

Comment: Thanks, this is far more helpful. I've revised the question a bit to clarify my point. So is there a single plane in which matter rotates around a black hole. See, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole#/media/File:Black_Holes_-_Monsters_in_Space.jpg

Comment: @Feynmanfan85, correct, a [rotating black hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_black_hole)'s accretion disk is (more or less) in the plane normal to the hole's angular momentum vector. Rotating black holes are also not spherically symmetric, and further, there are *two* horizons. Poke around here for Q & A related to [Kerr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr_metric) black holes

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. So then it is the case that the angle of interaction, and not just the distance is relevant - otherwise, how could the accretion disk form?

Comment: @Feynmanfan85, [A black hole, a disk, and an equator](https://cosmosmagazine.com/physics/a-black-hole-a-disc-and-an-equator)

Comment: Thanks! So it seems to be accepted that gravity is in fact not uniform around a black hole, but instead depends upon both the angle and the distance of observation.

Comment: @Feynmanfan85, I think that you're using *uniform* incorrectly here (and in the edited title). A uniform gravitation field has no spatial coordinate dependence at all (IINM, not possible in GR).  A spherically symmetric gravitational field has no angular coordinate dependence (think non-rotating black hole).  An axisymmetric gravitational field has no dependence on the angular coordinate about an axis (think rotating black hole)

Comment: There is no such thing as a gravitational field that has no dependence on position, that's why I didn't bother distinguishing that point. Uniform field means uniform at a fixed distance. I generally don't exclude things that aren't real.

Comment: @Feynmanfan85, I think that you're using *uniform* incorrectly here (and in the edited title).

Comment: How it could it mean anything else? There is no such thing as a uniform gravitational field of the sort you're suggesting. If you don't have an answer as to what force generates the accretion disk, then I think we can skip the semantics debate.

Comment: @Feynmanfan85, editing your question so dramatically is considered *bad form* here. I recommend that you revert the edits you've made to your question, post a new follow-up question, and link to this one for a reference.